# Setting events in loop works only for last element (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have multiple button elements and for each of them I want to create a separate input element to load a picture. Button has an `img` element within that soon will have a source of loaded picture.
Input elements quantity should be the same as number of buttons.

As I looked through some tips here, I firstly created inputs in a loop than tried to trigger click event on each input in a separate loop.
But unfortunately in result I see that all `button` refer to last `input`

```
pix = $("button[id*='picture-add-']") // all buttons I have
for (var i = 0; i < pix.length; ++i){
    i_selector = i+1 
    new_input = $('<input>', {
        id:"file-input-" + i_selector.toString(),
        type:"file",
        name:"name",
        style:"display: none;",
        accept:"image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png, image/jpeg"}).appendTo('#addNew') // each input is added to main bootstrap window
}
for (let i = 0; i < pix.length; ++i){
    i_sel = i+1
    pic_element_id = pix[i].id 
    input_element_id = $('#file-input-' + i_sel.toString())[0].id
    $('#' + pic_element_id).click(function(){
        $('#' + input_element_id).trigger('click')
        console.log(pic_element_id, 'pic_element_id')
        console.log(input_element_id) 
    })
}
```

Any time I click any button console prints that I pressed the last button. What part of this could be wrong?

Comment: for a simple fix, declare all your variables inside the loop with `let` keyword... what happens is, since you don't have let declaration, these variables get created on the parent (global) scope... and when the loop ends, your index becaomes the last index and thus, only the lest button shows effective behavior

Comment: @AdityaParab thanks that helped! Didn't know that `let` would help